# Updating code in old book to Xcode5

Tags: ios, opengl-es, xcode5

Totally new to iOS development. I have a book published in 2010 called iPhone 3d Programming. There is a file explained on page 23 that will not compile in XCode5. Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong or how to update this code to make it compile?

I"m getting errors like:

`Expected ';' at end of declaration list`

`Unknown type name 'virtual'`

IRendereringEngine.hpp

```
#ifndef HelloArrow_IRenderingEngine_hpp
#define HelloArrow_IRenderingEngine_hpp

// Physical orientation of a handheld device, equivalent to UIDeviceOrientation
enum DeviceOrientation {
    DeviceOrientationUnknown,
    DeviceOrientationPortrait,
    DeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
    DeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
    DeviceOrientationFaceUp,
    DeviceOrientationFaceDown
};

// Creates an instance of the renderer and setus up various OpenGL state
struct IRenderingEngine* CreateRenderer1();

// Interface to the OpenGL ES renderer, consumed by GLView
struct IRenderingEngine {
    virtual void Initialize (int width, int height) = 0;
    virtual void Render() const = 0;
    virtual void UpdateAnimation(float timeStep) = 0;
    virtual void OnRotate(DeviceOrientation newOrientation) = 0;
    virtual ~IRenderingEngine();
};

#endif
```

Comment: Which lines are the compiler saying has these errors?

Comment: Sorry. It's all of the lines in the struct. Each line has both errors.

Comment: What is the name of the file (compilation unit) where this header is being included?

Comment: same question got answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8178658/3296566